# How is it possible to use a special character (a star) in the "from" field using Perl's sendmail

Tags: perl, email, sendmail, mime, html-entities

I am using **Perl's SENDMAIL** to receive email from my website:

```
open(SENDMAIL, "|$sendmail") or die "Cannot open $sendmail: $!";
    print SENDMAIL "From: $from\n";
    print SENDMAIL "Subject: $subject\n";
    print SENDMAIL "To: $to\n";
    print SENDMAIL "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
    print SENDMAIL $message;
close(SENDMAIL);
```

And I would like to modify the **$from** variable to be something like this:

```
$from = "&#x2605; David Jones <david.jones@oozicle.com>"
```

What happens right now is that I just see the ampersand etc., and the star is not shown.

I know that it is possible to use special characters because I receive spam containing them.

**Is it possible to do this using SENDMAIL?**

Comment: This is not really a Perl question, as you are not really using Perl to do anything but pipe output to `sendmail` which is not "Perl's" in any way shape or form.

Comment: Thanks. I have only used it through Perl and I didn't think it through when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Encode qw( encode );

my $name = "\x{2605} David Jones";
my $addr = 'david.jones@oozicle.com';

my $from_header = encode('MIME-Header', $name) . ' <' . $addr . '>';
```

Comment: I don't know if you can encode the whole thing, but you can definitely encode the text part.

Comment: You solution is more general - int this very specific case (single utf8 character) the variant below may proude cleaner results `encode('MIME-B', "\x{2605}"). " David Jones <david.jones@oozicle.com>"`

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip, I don't know what you mean by cleaner since it's completely transparent to the user. Conventionally, mail clients encode the entire "name".

Comment: IMHO it would be cleaner from "raw email" perspective. You are right it *SHOULD NOT* make difference **but** "a few" email clients will display "raw" subject.